# Need some small info about AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to get complete resources/instances related details easily in excel or cloud formation template of our existing AWS account!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a service that AWS provides out of the box, you would need to make use of the [CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or [SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to retrieve these details in a format that matches what you want.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to get a list of all the resources in an account. You will have to use AWS CLI and use options like

```
aws configservice list-discovered-resources --resource-type
```

Where resource type is the type of resource you want to fetch the list for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, Can you please upvote it. It might help others too. Thanks

Comment: But when i try to list the buckets it showing like this   {
    "resourceIdentifiers": []
}

Comment: It can be because maybe you do not have any resources in that region.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/APIReference/API_ListAggregateDiscoveredResources.html
Check this link it might help you understand the request and response.

Comment: It requires that you have activated an AWS Config recorder. See: [Selecting Which Resources AWS Config Records - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/select-resources.html)